# How to create a file with '01' if name exists?

Tags: python, operating-system, built-in, file-manager

Is there a specific argument in open() built-in function so that if the filename already exists, it creates a file by adding a number to its name ??

such that if "file.txt" exists, it automatically creates "file-01.txt"

Or any other solution.!

Comment: There is no such flag. Have you read the documentation for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, Thanks!!

```
b = True
c = 1
while b:
    f_name = 'Task-{:02.0f}.txt'.format(c)
    try:
        f = open(f_name,'x')
        b = False
    except FileExistsError:
        c += 1
f.close()
```

Comment: Please upvote the answers that helped you and set the most useful one as accepted !

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there's something like this but you can do it yourself using `os.path.isfile` :

```
import os
filename = "yourFileName.txt"
if os.path.isfile(filename): #check if filename exists in the directory
    filename = filename.split(".")[:-1] + "-01" + filename.split(".")[-1]
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    f.write(yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import os
if os.path.exists(filename):
   fileparts = filename.split('.')
   filename = fileparts[0] + '01.'
   for a in fileparts[1:]:
     filename += a
```

Comment: No, if the filename is "file.txt" it becomes  "file.txt01" and if there's directory named like the filename it will return True!

Comment: sorry... had noticed that, but you caught me in between edits :-)

Answer (score 0):

See what you think of this.  ...this is what I use to do what you're looking for.  It's the smallest way I found to solve the problem before, and is easy to wrap into a function:

```
import os

name = 'blah.txt'

uniq_name = name
while os.path.isfile(uniq_name):
    # if increment variable 'delta' isn't defined, make it 1.  Otherwise increment
    delta = delta+1 if 'delta' in vars() else 1
    uniq_name = f'{os.path.splitext(name)[0]}-{delta}{os.path.splitext(name)[1]}'

# this you don't need - it's just equivalent to a 'touch' command to show
# the output
open(uniq_name, 'a').close()
```